# Overloading "+" operator for Thrust, any ideas?

Tags: c++, cuda, operator-keyword, nvidia, nvcc

I'm working with CUDA and Thrust. I find typing the `thrust::transform [plus/minus/divide]` tedious so I just want to overload some simple operators.

It would be awesome if I could do :

```
thrust::[host/device]_vector<float> host;
thrust::[host/device]_vector<float> otherHost;
thrust::[host/device]_vector<float> result = host + otherHost;
```

Here is an example snippet for `+`:

```
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__ T& operator+(T &lhs, const T &rhs) {
    thrust::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(),
                      lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), thrust::plus<?>());
    return lhs;
}
```

However, the `thrust::plus<?>` is not correctly overloaded, or I'm not doing it correctly... one or the other. (If overloading simple operators for this is a bad idea, please explain why). Initially, I thought that I could overload the `?` placeholder with something like `typename T::iterator`, but that didn't work.

I'm not sure how to overload the `+` operator with both the type of the vector *and* the type of the vector iterator. Does this make sense?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's does the `<?>` mean?

Comment: @Elazar It means I don't know what to put in there. Maybe some type of `T::iterator` type or something.

Comment: You can say "I don't know what should I put as a template parameter for `thrust::plus`"

Comment: I'm trying to obtain the template parameter for `thrust::plus` via the template parameter from `thrust::host_device`. If it isn't clear, edit the question yourself.

Comment: You may be interested in [this library](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/newton) which has already implemented what you're attempting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, others may have better ideas:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>

#define DSIZE 10


template <typename T>
thrust::device_vector<T>  operator+(thrust::device_vector<T> &lhs, const thrust::device_vector<T> &rhs) {
    thrust::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(),
                      lhs.begin(), lhs.begin(), thrust::plus<T>());
    return lhs;
}

template <typename T>
thrust::host_vector<T>  operator+(thrust::host_vector<T> &lhs, const thrust::host_vector<T> &rhs) {
    thrust::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(),
                      lhs.begin(), lhs.begin(), thrust::plus<T>());
    return lhs;
}
int main() {


  thrust::device_vector<float> dvec(DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<float> otherdvec(DSIZE);
  thrust::fill(dvec.begin(), dvec.end(), 1.0f);
  thrust::fill(otherdvec.begin(), otherdvec.end(), 2.0f);
  thrust::host_vector<float> hresult1 = dvec + otherdvec;

  std::cout << "result 1: ";
  thrust::copy(hresult1.begin(), hresult1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));  std::cout << std::endl;

  thrust::host_vector<float> hvec(DSIZE);
  thrust::fill(hvec.begin(), hvec.end(), 5.0f);
  thrust::host_vector<float> hresult2 = hvec + hresult1;


  std::cout << "result 2: ";
  thrust::copy(hresult2.begin(), hresult2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));  std::cout << std::endl;

  // this line would produce a compile error:
  // thrust::host_vector<float> hresult3 = dvec + hvec;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that in either case, I can specify a host or device vector for the result, since thrust will see the difference and automatically generate the necessary copy operation.  So the result vector type (host, device) in my templates is not critical.

Also note that the `thrust::transform` function parameters you had in your template definition weren't quite right.

Comment: Ah, I think that will work. I'll check it when I get back to work in the morning.

Comment: I guess one other thing I should have pointed out is that (I think) you were suggesting an in-place tranform (which is why you proposed returning `lhs`, and I followed your convention), but the effect of that is one of the two operands (lhs) is getting overwritten.  So this might create the slightly non-intuitive behavior that `result = vec1 + vec2;` puts the answer in *both* `result` and `vec1`.